# Glitchy lines coming from the pencil strokes

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, object-mode

There are these weird glitchy lines coming from the end of the stroke while I'm drawing. They also connect the two last strokes I put down between each other. Because of that, when i switch do Object Mode the whole drawing is one single object

I use a graphics tablet, so I thought it was a problem with pen pressure. I tried messing with different pressure sensitivity setting, but it didn't help.

Later I found out that if I hide one of two active scene collections it makes the glitching better and it disappears for the most part.

Version: 2.92.0

[image]

[image]

Update:
This is how the rendering looks:
[image]